# Echo PHP code into existing div tag

Tags: php

I have written out a template for a website with my divs for content and etc, and I have php code which echoes commands, e.g. 'Fill in all the fields' but when it echoes it writes it out at the top of the window.

I want to know how can I echo the code into an existing div tag, which I created for my content.

Thanks

Comment: `<div id='content'><?php echo $stuff; ?></div>` If `$stuff` contains any HTML special characters, `<div id='content'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($stuff); ?></div>`

Comment: @Michael has a very succinct answer, thought you can also use the [`printf` function](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php); it's a bit old school, admittedly.

Comment: @Mark `printf()` is far more specialized, for creating formatted strings. Old school, but powerful, and probably beyond the OP's needs.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to create a pair of HTML tags, e.g

```
<div></div>.
```

Inside them open up a pair of php tags and echo something out. Like

```
<div><?php echo $something; ?></div>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, this will just echo out a new div and not insert what he wanted inside the already present content of his/her page.